# Browser detect code in PHP not detecting Opera

Tags: php, opera, browser-detection

I found the code in [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php). This seems to be a nice and simple code, it can detect google chrome, firefox, IE and safari however it cannot detect Opera.

```
OUTPUT in OPERA:
Your browser: Google Chrome 45.0.2454.93 on windows reports: 
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36 OPR/32.0.1948.69
```

Need help in modifying this code so it can detect opera.

```
  <?php
    function getBrowser()
    {
        $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        $bname = 'Unknown';
        $platform = 'Unknown';
        $version= "";

        //First get the platform?
        if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
            $platform = 'linux';
        }
        elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
            $platform = 'mac';
        }
        elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
            $platform = 'windows';
        }

        // Next get the name of the useragent yes seperately and for good reason
        if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Internet Explorer';
            $ub = "MSIE";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Trident/i',$u_agent))
        { // this condition is for IE11
            $bname = 'Internet Explorer';
            $ub = "rv";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox';
            $ub = "Firefox";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Google Chrome';
            $ub = "Chrome";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Apple Safari';
            $ub = "Safari";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Opera';
            $ub = "Opera";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Netscape';
            $ub = "Netscape";
        }

        // finally get the correct version number
        // Added "|:"
        $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
        $pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .
         ')[/|: ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
        if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
            // we have no matching number just continue
        }

        // see how many we have
        $i = count($matches['browser']);
        if ($i != 1) {
            //we will have two since we are not using 'other' argument yet
            //see if version is before or after the name
            if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
                $version= $matches['version'][0];
            }
            else {
                $version= $matches['version'][1];
            }
        }
        else {
            $version= $matches['version'][0];
        }

        // check if we have a number
        if ($version==null || $version=="") {$version="?";}

        return array(
            'userAgent' => $u_agent,
            'name'      => $bname,
            'version'   => $version,
            'platform'  => $platform,
            'pattern'    => $pattern
        );
    }

    // now try it
    $ua=getBrowser();
    $yourbrowser= "Your browser: " . $ua['name'] . " " . $ua['version'] . " on " .$ua['platform'] . " reports: <br >" . $ua['userAgent'];
    print_r($yourbrowser);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's working now after some changes...

I changed this part....

```
 elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Opera';
            $ub = "Opera";
        }
```

to

```
 elseif(preg_match('/OPR/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Opera';
            $ub = "OPR";
        }
```

Comment: still it says "chrome" on opera browser!

Answer (score 2):

well, in opera

first check opera then for Chrome as the $u_agent is showing Chrome/, Safari/ and OPR/ in the result of $u_agent. So check for Opera as soon as you done with internet explorer by changing the code suggested by @aabejero.

```
elseif(preg_match('/OPR/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Opera';
            $ub = "OPR";
        }
```

if you don't do this sometime in Opera it gives Google Chrome as Browser

Comment: No! I tried on Opera v79 & 80. It says "Safari" on opera. Ridiculious answer!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the basic function given in documentation `get_browser`.

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
?>
```

In order for this to work, your browscap configuration setting in **php.ini** must point to the correct location of the **browscap.ini** file on your system.

browscap.ini is not bundled with PHP, you can download it [here](http://browscap.org/)

Comment: I checked browscap in php.ini configuration setting and its already configured, and browscap.ini is included in php file.

[browscap]
; http://php.net/browscap
browscap = "C:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini"

I downloaded the php_browscap.ini in the link you gave and replace the original browscap.ini and reconfigure php setting however still not detecting opera, anyway I appreciate your help